# Unable to add Newly Created Files to SVN

Tags: intellij-idea, svn, commit

There seems to be a problem adding newly created files to subversion through Intellij, because when I right click on any of them, the option to add them is grayed out and only `Revert` is accessible:
[image]

By the way, this problem only appears with newly added files, the old ones are detectable and can be edited and committed without problem.

Maybe I missed something when I created them?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Basically all VCS operations for ignored files are expected to be unavailable. Aren`t there some exclusions set up accidentally?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was really simple. Here's how I did, hopefully this will help someone else one day:

1. Leave Intellij (or the IDE you're using) aside and open your command prompt.
2. CD to the root of your project.
3. Manually add the files that you have created with the command `add`.

   Example: svn add path/to/your/file.java
4. Go back to Intellij, you should see all your files which weren't detected before change color from yellow to green.
5. You can now commit your new files.